# Difference in Application performance running in IIS and Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, iis, web-applications

I have a web application that works fine in IIS 6.0. I have modified to make it work in Apache Tomcat also.

1. Will there be any visible changes in performance between the 2?
2. Are there any specific advantages or limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a web application that works
>   fine in IIS 6.0. I have modified to
>   make it work in Apache Tomcat also.

Do you mean `Web site` or `Web application`? How did you `modify` it?

There are many [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092564/java-and-tomcat-vs-asp-net-and-iis) to help you with comparing the performance.

Advantages?Limitations?? Well, basically Apache Tomcat is a full fledged web-container which supports Java based web applications (Servlets, JSP,...) and IIS helps you with ASP/ASP.NET web-applications basically (of course, you can configure [IIS with Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/tomcat-iis-howto.html)). Altogether your question 2 is too vague to answer. Experts, might be able to help you.

Comment: Assume "I have modified to make it work in Apache Tomcat also. 
"

Comment: @ckv- I mean, how is it possible. Suppose that you have written a web application in ASP.net? How can you just `modify` it to run in Apache Tomcat? You have to re-write the entire app using JSP/Servlets/... to run on Tomcat. If you mean to do that, try the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092564/java-and-tomcat-vs-asp-net-and-iis) I have mentioned above

Comment: Just thinking of a hypothetical possibility.